# Assign large type variable to a smaller types array

Tags: c++, arrays, int32, uint8t

I am just wondering how this works, and to be clear as to whether it actually does work.

If you have a 32 bit int and an 8 bit int array of size 4. Can you assign the 32 bit int to the 0th index in the 8 bit int array and effectively have the same value, bit wise.
Also if you then wanted to convert it back I presume you could fill up the 32 bit int with the array and appropriate bit shifts.

```
int32 bigVbl   = 20;
int8  smallVbl[4];

smallVbl[0] = bigVbl;
```

I expect the smallVbl array to hold the entirety of bigVbl.

Comment: You could do it by converting to and from a `char *` without using the `char *` in between, but I don't think that's quite what you were going for. A union is probably what you were looking for, but even then it's usually technically UB and we still don't know what you're truly seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignments always truncate the most significant bits and retain the LSBs. Other arithmetics operations truncate the result too, if it overflows. In that way you can extend the maths (and many other operations) for operating on big integers easily. Without truncation how can you crammed 32 bits into 8 bits?

To copy the 32-bit int into an array of 4 8-bit chars, the easiest ways is copy the whole number into the array. Another way is assign element-by-element

```
smallVbl[0] = bigVbl & 0xff; // the & 0xff is not really needed
smallVbl[1] = (bigVbl >> 8) & 0xff;
smallVbl[2] = (bigVbl >> 16) & 0xff;
smallVbl[3] = (bigVbl >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Comment: I didn't want to cram 32 bits into 8 bits... obviously. 
I just figured as I had in a sense offered 32 bits of array to fill, it might not truncate.
I've obviously thought it through a bit more now :)
This was practically the method I went for. Minus the mask, as that was unnecessary in all 4 cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing it, the simplest probably being to use [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) to copy the integer into the array:

```
std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<int8*>(&bigVbl),           // Source to copy from
            std::min(sizeof(smallVbl), sizeof(bigVbl)), // Number of bytes to copy
            smallVbl);                                  // Destination to copy to
```

To copy the opposite direction, just switch place of the source and destination in the above call.

Comment: So are you suggesting my method would not do what I require? i.e. only the first value of the array would be populated, with the last 8 bits of the int32.

Comment: @TomPenfold No, the assignment truncates the value in `bigVbl` to just the lowest 8 bits, the rest of the array will be unmodified.

Comment: Bummer, I hoped it would be clever enough not to truncate.

Comment: @Tom: It's clever enough to truncate

Comment: That's definitely one perspective